# How to check a value is inside nested dictionary swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a problem concerning my nested dictionary.

```
var level1Dictionary = [String : [String : String]]()
var ChosenDeckLabel = [String]
textview.text
```

I want to see if the dictionary contains a certain value within my, `else if` statement as such:

```
else if level1Dictionary[ChosenDeckLabel[textview.text]] != nil {
```

this returns error:

> Cannot subscript value of type String with an index of type String!

How should I cast it to check if the nested dictionary contains the value?

Comment: Where is the error given? Can you give us some sample data input, and the output you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you intend to do:

`else if level1Dictionary[strIndex1][strIndex2] != nil {`

Comment: Haha :) Yea thanks, I've used it all wrong. All the answers is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are optionals by default because they are not sure if a key/value pair exist. Be sure to include your "!" AND "?" to wrap and unwrap your data being passed.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays offer subscripting via integers and ranges as seen in Swift's API:

```
public subscript (index: Int) -> Element
public subscript (subRange: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element>
```

You're trying to subscript via a string which is throwing the error. You need to get the index of the element in the array and then use that to subscript the array to get the value: e.g.

```
let dictOfDicts = [String : [String : String]]()
var arrayOfStrings: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]
let stringToCheck = "a"

dictOfDicts["a"] = ["some": "thing"]

if let index = array.indexOf(stringToCheck) {
    if dictOfDicts[array[Int(index)]] != nil {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing this:

```
level1Dictionary[ChosenDeckLabel[textview.text]]
```

you are trying to access the `ChosenDeckLabel` `array` using a `String` subscript:

```
ChosenDeckLabel[textview.text]
```

which is not a valid operation. Arrays are `Int` indexed and not string indexed.